# SQLite short file names 8.3

Tags: sqlite

I am attempting to compile SQLite for an operating system that does not support long file names. The max file name is 8 chars long with an extension of 3 chars (8.3).

Currently a "-journal" is created while using SQLite this breaks the file name rule and stops SQLite with "Disk I/O Error"

I have tried to disable the journal from being created in the first place with "PRAGMA journal_mode OFF" but it appears that the file still gets created then destroyed.

- Is there anyway (compile flag or PRAGMA, ect) to force SQLite to use 8.3 file names?
- Is there anyway to disable the journal from being created?

Not Windows, not Unix, not OS2, other OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Since you need to create a [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html) for your "Not Windows, not Unix, not OS2, other OS" you could have its xOpen function translate "name.sdb-joural" into "name.jnl"

Option 2: Modify sqlite3PagerOpen to use a different mechanism, such as changing the file extension, to make the journal name